# What is the equivalent for NO ORDER of oracle sequence in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, database-sequence

I have a query

```
CREATE SEQUENCE  "SEQ_ID"  
    MINVALUE 1 
    MAXVALUE 99999 
    INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 121 
    CACHE 20 
    NOORDER  
    NOCYCLE;
```

This one is of oracle commands.

Now, I want to convert into a PostgreSQL command.

How do I replace NO ORDER here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How do I replace NO ORDER here.

Just remove it.

There is no equivalent, and I you probably didn't need (or specify) it in Oracle to begin with.

In Oracle `ORDER` is only needed in a RAC environment and `NOORDER` is the default.

So the equivalent would be:

```sql
CREATE SEQUENCE seq_id
    MINVALUE 1 
    MAXVALUE 99999 
    INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 121 
    CACHE 20 
    NO CYCLE;
```

I removed the double quotes because you should avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers.

Comment: THANKS .But if , i have max value as  9999999999999999999999999999, I get an error stating **out of range for type bigint** .                                                         
CREATE SEQUENCE  seq_id  MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1 CACHE 20 NO CYCLE 
;Please guide!!! @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: Use `NO MAXVALUE` instead